# Clarification on a clipper circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, voltage-clipping

I'm reading a paper whose result I am trying to replicate. One of the circuit elements is a clipper circuit as shown below.

[image]

This is a very straight-forward circuit. The positive value is limited to \$V_1 + V_{diode}\$ and the negative value is limited to \$V_2 - V_{diode}\$, where \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ are the two series voltage sources.

The author is trying to use this circuit to product a sigmoidal voltage response.

[image]

According to my equations above, this means, assuming \$V_{diode} = 0.7\$, we should set \$V_1 = 0.3\$ and \$V_2 = 0.7\$. Both the chose \$V_1 = 0.3\$ and \$V_2 = -0.7\$.

[image]

Here is a simulation with \$V_1 = 0.3\$ and \$V_2 = 0.7\$.

[image]

[image]

Here is a simulation with \$V_1 = 0.3\$ and \$V_2 = -0.7\$.

[image]

[image]

The author says the output voltage is linear in the range between 0 and 1V. Using his values for the series voltages source, the output voltage is linear in the range between -1.4 and 1V. I tried using his values to replicate this circuit:

[image]

... using the resistance values from the image below, but had vastly different node voltages:

[image]

I also tried using \$V_1 = 0.3\$ and \$V_2 = 0.7\$, but also didn't get similar node voltages. Am I missing something or did the author mistyped \$V_2 = -0.7\$ for \$V_2 = 0.7\$.

Comment: Since you don't have $V_1$ or $V_2$ marked on the schematic, it is impossible to know the polarity of "-0.7 V" in the text.

Comment: The author didn't specify. I took V1 to be the left voltage source and V2 to be the right voltage source, and their orientation as shown in the figure.

Answer (score 0):

The linear region is the region where none of the diodes conduct. If we assume the polarity of the voltage sources are as shown in the schematic then it is obvious. You are right. He probably mistyped it.

It should be noted though that this doesn't seem a practical circuit to implement. Would you care to share the paper's title?

Comment: Here's a link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01981
My goal is to just replicate the result in simulation.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I read the paper. Are you trying to simulate it in LTSpice?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use his resistor values for the XOR circuit on his paper and drew the circuit as he indicated but got very different results. Here's the [schematic](https://i.imgur.com/jMQ85lU.png) I used. It looks more complicated than it needs to be because I tried to make it more realistic. Because I wasn't getting the expected values, I decide to train a circuit myself. Here's a [python](https://pastebin.com/nUXJVHkR)  script I threw together to do just that. It learns for a while, but after that the loss starts increasing again.

Comment: In the spice model, why are R12 and R13 in parallel?

Comment: Sorry, that's an old circuit I sent you. I had cleaned things up. This is the [circuit](https://i.imgur.com/RCfhhU1.png) I am using. There are a couple of things I have noticed that maybe you can shed some light on:
1. The choice of the series voltage sources for the non-linearity affect the result greatly.
2. While training the resistances seem to change extremely slowly. As a result, the random values that they get initialized almost determines how well the training goes.

Comment: 3. I am currently using np.random.uniform(L, U, size=size) to initialize the resistances. Since U is much larger than L, most values are closer to U. I trained using a logarithmic scale, but that since the circuit is very slow to change the resistance values, having very initial values seem to be worse.

4. I have noticed that even after injecting current at the output during the training phase, the change in the voltage drop in the resistors is very tiny. Do you know why this could be the case?

5. Could you suggest any way to improve the non-linearity circuit?

Comment: What I would do first is to replace the non-linearity part with an ideal circuit (just put a sigmoid function in X3 and X4) just to see if the problem comes from there. Most of the circuit uses ideal components anyway. I must also let you know that last time I set foot to a university was more than 20 years ago so don't expect world class consulting :) . Cheers.